# Finding dimension of a kernel from a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to solve an exercise where I'm asked to find this linear transformation's kernel and its dimension:

$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(x_1-x_2,2x_3+x_4)$$

So, from the definition of kernel and converting to parametric equations, I found $x_1=x_2=\lambda$, $x_3=-\frac{1}{2}\mu$ and $x_4=\mu$. Therefore, I assumed: $$\ker(f)=\{(\lambda,\lambda,-\frac{1}{2}\mu,\mu): \lambda,\mu \in  \mathbb{R}\}$$

And since the kernel can be described with only one vector (with two parameters), I thought $\dim(\ker(f))=1$, but my textbook says it's actually equal to $2$. Where is my reasoning flawed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A basis for the kernel is $\{(1,1,0,0), (0,0,-\frac{1}{2}, 1) \}$

Comment: @leibnewtz Hm, so that means I can only 'fix' one parameter at once? I thought it'd be possible to establish something like $\lambda=1$, $\mu=2$ so that a basis for the kernel is $\{(1,1,-1,2)\}$. Why isn't that possible?

Comment: Of course you can do what you say...but that way you'll only get **one** vector, and you *already* know you need two lin. ind. vectors to have a basis...

Comment: Since $f:\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R^2$, its image is at most two-dimensional, so you know that its kernel must be *at least* two-dimensional.

Comment: @Manuel Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all correct, the **dimension of the ker(f) is 2** because you have **2 free parameters** that define it $(\lambda,\mu)$.

Comment: Oh, I thought the definition of dimension refered to the number of vector, but accounting for the number of parameters necessary to define those vectors makes more sense. Is it that intuitive?

Comment: @Manuel They are equivalent concepts. As noted in the comments you can set $\lambda=1$ and $\mu=0$ and define a basis vector, then $\lambda=0$ and $\mu=1$ and define a second vector linearly independent from the first, thus the dimension is 2. This is true for any number of free parameter (EG a line or a plane in $\mathbb{R^3}$).

Comment: @Manuel There *are* two vectors in your description of the kernel: $\left(\lambda,\lambda,-\frac12\mu,\mu\right)=\lambda(1,1,0,0)+\mu\left(0,0,-\frac12,1\right)$; every vector in the kernel is a linear combination of these two linearly-independent vectors.

Comment: @amd, that makes a lot of sense, thanks!